# TcpClient / TcpListener filename

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm implementing a simple file sending method based on the example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396454/sending-binary-file-tcpclient-file-is-larger-than-source), however I'm having trouble finding any reference on how to go about sending the filename and/or type before sending the actual bytes. All the examples I've seen, manually set the filename on the receiving end.

My only thought so far is sending it separately as a string, but I was just curious if I'm missing some easier/convenient way of doing this. So, is there a method within the TcpClient/TcpListener to send the filename that I've missed? Is there a common way of doing this that I simply haven't run across?

If necessary I can post the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can send is "data", a flat array of bytes. So you will need to use a some kind of protocol both sender and listener apply to the data.

You could say you want to transfer "two blocks of data", in which case you could:

- send the size of each block, followed by the actual data, followed by the next block size and data, or:
- use a separator character (which only works if the actual data does not contain that separator (and even then there are solutions like escaping the separator in the data))

Alternatively you could *format* the data, for instance by sending an Xml document, containing:

```
<myData>
  <filename>txt.txt</filename>
  <data>F83BA=</data>
</myData>
```

The problem being of course that the file contents would have to be *encoded* in order for the Xml to be validated (base64 encoding for example).