# c# app stops responding on recieving file over tcp

Tags: c#, tcp

I was trying to recieve xml file with simple tcp server. But all my efforts ends with crushing application on reading bytes from NetworkStream. I have no idea, what is wrong.

I have already tried to copy source code from the answer to a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396454/sending-binary-file-tcpclient-file-is-larger-than-source). It looks like it should work, but it doesn't

Code sample of my client sending xml:

```
private void SendFile()
{
    // stm is a class attribue NetworkStream defined in another method 
    byte[] dataToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(string_path_to_file);             
    stm.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
    sstm.Flush();
}
```

Code sample of my server recieving xml:

```
 public void RecieveFile()
    {
            Stream fs = new FileStream(path_to_recieved_file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            int length;
            //client was defined earlier, on establishing connection
            NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
            length = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            while ((length = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                  fs.Write(bytes, 0, length);
            }  
    }
```

Client works fine. I am sending test xml file (~533b) and server can read these data. When I debugging my app, I can see that first time server will read 533b (obviously, the whole file). Then writes it and stops responding after trying to read second time. I expected that after second reading, when there is nothing in networkStream, I'll get length=0 and loop will stop. What am I doing wrong?

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading to the end of the stream - however, this will not happen until you **close** the sending socket. Until the socket is closed, it is in a limbo pending state, and it is correct and expected that `Read` will block indefinitely, until one of:

- the stream becomes closed (or faulted)
- at least one byte is available
- read timeout, if enabled

Incidentally, you are discarding the first chunk of data you read. If you are in a position to close the sending stream, you should just replace all of that code with:

```
using(var fs = File.Create(path_to_recieved_file)) {
    client.GetStream().CopyTo(fs);
}
```

However, if you **cannot** close the sending stream (because you want to send multiple messages, for example), you will need to implement some kind of framing protocol - for example, prefixing the data with the payload length.

Comment: Oh...didn't know, that I have to close it now. Thank! 
Will it help, if the client send size of file to a server and only after that send the whole file? So server will read only expected amount of bytes?

Comment: @Mad can you rephrase that? I can't understand the question.

Comment: 1) Client will send size of a file 
2) After that client will send file with my SendFile() method
3) Server will recieve size of extected file 
4) Server will read only expected # of bytes. So I will be able to stop reading loop when length will be equal to expected size of file.

Comment: @Mad that can work, but that is *not* what the code you have posted does

Comment: Yeah, I know. I will try to fix it. At least now I know what was my problem. 
Thank you! It really helped!